# Taking the sum of user inputs and storing it as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

What is the best way to calculate sum of user inputs from an array and then store that value as a variable?

I have a function here that creates an array from user inputs(number4[]).

var counter = 1;

```
var limit = 3;

function addInput(divName){

     if (counter == limit)  {

          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");

     }

     else {

          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

          newdiv.innerHTML = "Asset($) " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='number4[]'>";

          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

          counter++;

     }
```

```
    <div class="container7">

        <div id ="dynamicInput">
        Assets 1($): <INPUT type="text" name="number4[]">
        </div>

        Liabilities 1(%): <INPUT type="text" name="number5">

        Result($): <INPUT type="text" name="total1"> 

        <INPUT type="button" style="background-color:#FF8800; border-color:BLACK;" value="Calculate"onclick="javascript:networth()">



        <INPUT type="button" style="background-color:#FF8800; border-color:BLACK;" value="Add asset fields"onclick="addInput('dynamicInput');">

    </div>

</FORM>
```

I have no code for total1 yet. so basically i have the array i just need help identifying the sum and then assigning it as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName("number4[]")` will return an array of the elements you need to total up

```
function networth(){
    var totNo = document.getElementsByName("number4[]").length;
    var sum = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<totNo; i++){
        sum += parseInt(document.getElementsByName("number4[]")[i].value);
        console.log(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. How would you take the sum that we just calculated and then subtract it by a var = liabilities_1 if liabilities_1 has a value? Is there a way to assign the sum we just calculated to a variable so we could do a simple function of sum - liabilities_1?

Comment: You will need to give the input for liabilities an id
<INPUT type="number" name="number5" `id="liabilities"`>

Then you just need to get the value from it using the id and do the maths with that and sum

`var lia = sum*((document.getElementById("liabilities").value)/100);
    var final = sum-lia;
     console.log(final);
`

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your input elements and use 
    var val1 = document.getElementById("the id of the input you want").value
    //repete for val2... with a different id and add the val variables

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all the input elements you want to sum. You can use the querySelectorAll to get all the elements with a same CSS selector common in all the inputs you want to sum.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

Finally you can get the input in the same way with querySelector, as is only one there is no need to use the All variation.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

```js
var counter = 1;
var limit = 3;
function networth(){
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("form #dynamicInput input");
  var networth = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    networth += parseFloat(inputs[i].value);
  }
  document.querySelector("input[name=total1]").value=networth;
}
function addInput(divName) {
  if (counter == limit) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "Asset($) " + (counter + 1) +
      " <br><input type='text' name='number4[]'>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="container7">

    <div id="dynamicInput">
      Assets 1($):<br>
      <INPUT type="text" name="number4[]">
    </div>

    Liabilities 1(%):
    <INPUT type="text" name="number5"> Result($):

    <INPUT type="text" name="total1">

    <INPUT type="button" style="background-color:#FF8800; border-color:BLACK;" value="Calculate" onclick="javascript:networth()" />

    <INPUT type="button" style="background-color:#FF8800; border-color:BLACK;" value="Add asset fields" onclick="addInput('dynamicInput');" />

  </div>

</FORM>
```